# LeetCode: (26: Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a problem in LeetCode, which is (26. Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array), and it's saying that my code is incorrect, while it works perfectly in VS Code.
Here is the code:

```js
let nums = [1, 1, 2]
let k = 0
const removeDuplicates = nums => {
  nums = [...new Set(nums)]
  k = nums.length
  return k + '\n' + nums
}
console.log(removeDuplicates(nums))
```

my question is why does the code works in vs code but not in Leet code?
[This is the code in Leet Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89EmU.png) [This is the code in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBVFH.png)

Comment: return `nums`, not `k`

Comment: Why do you need `k` at all?

Comment: LeetCode.com: `You must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.` The code rendered in "the LeetCode hyperlink" does not match what's presented here.

Comment: @greybeard Thanks for replying, but I'm confused, i didn't use another array, all the changes are in the original one... and the error that appears tells me that the array output is wrong while it's right, this is the important part.

Comment: @greybeard here is the question if you'd like to see [26](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/)  and u can copy my solution to try it, you'll see that they're saying the array output is wrong though it's right. I'm having this problem again right now actually, all code is good, though they're saying the array output is wrong. if u want to see u can tell me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    const set = new Set(nums);
    let i = 0;
    set.forEach(num => {
      nums[i] = num
      i++
    })

    return set.size;
};
```

Comment: sadly, this doesn't follow the question's instructions

Answer (score 0):

- [The question](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/) asks for a numeric result, but your `removeDuplicates` function returns a multi-line string.
- The duplicates should be removed [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm), that is, *without* using auxiliary data structures like `new Set(…)`.

Comment: Thank you, my vs code returns a multiline string but in leetcode it's jus (K) what i'm returning. thanks again.